# Xamarin.Forms SOAP deserialisation fails on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, soap, webservice-client

In a Xamarin.Forms project, I have strange effects deserializing a WebService response.

On server side I have

```
namespace MyTestWebservice
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "https://example.com/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public class AppInterface : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public GeneralClass TestMethod(int param)
        {
            return /* Resulting instance */
        }
    }
}
```

with the following data:

```
namespace MyTestWebservice
{       
    [XmlInclude(typeof(TestClass1))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(TestClass2))]
    public abstract class TestBase
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestClass1 : TestBase
    {
        public int Prop3 { get; set; }
        public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestClass2 : TestBase
    {
        public int Prop5 { get; set; }
        public string Prop6 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Other
    {
        public string Prop7 { get; set; }
    }

    public class GeneralClass
    {
        public int Prop0 { get; set; }
        public TestBase[] Values { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In VisualStudio 2022 I generated code to send/receive requests to the Web Service. The code looks ok (as far as I can see) and in MyApp.UWP (Server on Windows, client on Windows) everything works well, i.e. all data is transferred correctly from server to app.

In MyApp.Android (Server on Windows, client on Android Emulator) however, only data of base class `TestBase` and referenced class `Other` is set, whereas data in `TestClass1` and `TestClass2` remains unset, i.e. `0` or `null`.

Is this a known bug in Xamarin.Forms and how can I work around? Or are some more attributes needed on some properties / class definitions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1994):

The problem is that on client side, XmlElementAttribute with parameter `Order` is attached to the properties in the generated code:

```
public class TestBase
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)] 
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)] 
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

For properties in the derived classes `TestClass1` and `TestClass2`, however, `Order` starts counting at `0` instead of `2`. Thus, after generating client code in Visual Studio, I must change orders by hand. Then all works well on Android.

Is there a newer version where this bug has been fixed?